# Vue.js decorators and moment.js with typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I'm getting an typescript error when using vue.js with the moment.js library with vue decorators. It only occurs inside the prop section of the class.

```
import * as moment from 'moment';

import { Vue, Component, Watch, Prop } from 'vue-property-decorator';

@Component({
  name: 'TestMoment',
  props: {
    tomorrow: moment.Moment,
  }
})
export default class TestMoment extends Vue {
  private date: moment.Moment = moment();
  public created() {
    console.log(this.date);
  }
}
```

The specific error is on the tomorrow property and I get:

```
Property 'Moment' does not exist on type 'typeof moment'. Did you mean 'isMoment'?
```

I have an editor which highlights errors and mousing over the `moment` on the line with `tomorrow` indicates the error, but not on the line `private date...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`type` of a VueJS prop must be a native constructor](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Type-Checks): in this case, you should be using `Object` instead, i.e.:

```
@Component({
  name: 'TestMoment',
  props: {
    tomorrow: Object,
  }
})
```

The `tomorrow` prop is typeof `object` and is an instance of `moment`, so you can perform the following check using the more declarative `@Prop` decorator instead, by supplying a custom validator function:

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
import { Vue, Component, Watch, Prop } from 'vue-property-decorator';

@Component({
  name: 'TestMoment',
  props: {
    tomorrow: moment.Moment,
  }
})
export default class TestMoment extends Vue {
  @Prop({ type: Object, validator: moment.isMoment })
  public readonly tomorrow!: moment.Moment;

  private date: moment.Moment = moment();
  public created() {
    console.log(this.date);
  }
}
```

You can also choose to hint TypeScript on the type of the returned object, using `type: Object as () => moment.Moment`:

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
import { Vue, Component, Watch, Prop } from 'vue-property-decorator';

@Component({
  name: 'TestMoment',
})
export default class TestMoment extends Vue {
  @Prop({ type: Object as () => moment.Moment, validator: moment.isMoment })
  public readonly tomorrow!: moment.Moment;

  private date: moment.Moment = moment();
  public created() {
    console.log(this.date);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Moment constructor function isn't exported from the package and kept private. [`Moment` is an interface](https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/2.24.0/moment.d.ts#L415) and don't exist at runtime, while it should exist in order to provided as property value:

```
  props: {
    tomorrow: moment.Moment,
  }
```

Moment object can be naturally provided as a prop with a validator:

```
  props: {
    tomorrow: {
      type: Object,
      validator: moment.isMoment
    }
  }
```

And it's possible to extract `Moment` constructor to make props pass `instanceof` runtime checks:

```
const Moment = moment.fn.constructor as { new(): typeof moment };

...

  props: {
    tomorrow: Moment,
  }
```